# Как плавно переместить объект к нужной позиции без потери скорости?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я бы использовал Vector3.Lerp, но он уменьшает скорость в конце(не совсем так, но так легче объяснить)

Comment: если у вас физический объект, то могу предложить только расчет расстояния и изменение velocity. Рассчитывать distance между объектом и точкой и если distance <= offest тогда object.<rigidbody>.velocity = 0

Comment: Vector3.MoveTowards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lerp` замедляет скорость в конце? Брешешь.

```
private void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(LerpCoroutine(transform, 1f, new Vector3(10, 10, 0));
}

private IEnumerator LerpCoroutine (Transform trans, float time, Vector3 target) {
    float Timer = 0;
    Vector3 Base = trans.localPosition;
    while (Timer < time) {
         trans.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(Base, target, Timer/time);
        yield return null;
        Timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    trans.localPosition = target;
}
```

Comment: Не брешу:P Как я и сказал "это не совсем так", но суть в том что скорость движения  в конце - меньше. Спасибо за помощь:)